# Stop recurring email in thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

I scheduled a recurring email every monday at 8:00 am on Thunderbird but I already received an answer. How can I make sure that I won't send this message again? I use the Send later add-on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from the extension managers:

> Messages live in the Drafts folder until their scheduled send time arrives, so you can just delete the message from the Drafts folder when you want to cancel it recurring. You can also open it for editing (which will also cancel it from sending, but without deleting it) or move it to a location besides the Drafts folder. All of the above will have the same effect.